# Logout user when admin blocks using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

Here I have a little bit confusion in my coding. And my problem is, When the user logged in to his account. At that time,If admin blocks the user whoever is logged in. And if the user clicks on any link then the user must be logout.

I have created a bunch of controller in my project. So, I don't like to make a change in all the controllers. How to write the code in short and sweet.?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend Your `CI_Controller` and add in `__constructor()` validation is user blocked/not